Using protofub in C++ when compiling to WASM with emscripten. Error compiling example from documentation
I need help figuring out a problem

I am rewriting part of the javascript library to wasm.

I compile the c++ code to wasm using this command: emcc idw.cpp -Oz -s WASM=1 -s --no-entry -o idw.wasm (emcc --version => 3.1.70)

I have a ready-made solution (MVP). But I am not satisfied with its speed, since I have to use json to transfer data


I decided to try using protobuf. To understand how to work with it, I am trying to repeat this simple example from the documentation
https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/

Using this command: protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. addressbook.proto, I got the *.pb.cc , *.pb.h files (protoc --version => libprotoc 25.1). addressbook.proto taken from the example

Added the following lines to my idw.cpp file


#include "proto/addressbook.**pb.h**"
    
const int justDoIt() {
    tutorial::AddressBook address_book;
    
    return 1;
}


I execute the command emcc idw.cpp -Oz -s WASM=1 -s --no-entry -o idw.wasm

I get the error:



wasm-ld: error:
C:\Users\DellPC\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_lcwq3urd\idw_0.o:
undefined symbol: tutorial::AddressBook::~AddressBook() wasm-ld:
error:
C:\Users\DellPC\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_lcwq3urd\idw_0.o:
undefined symbol:
tutorial::AddressBook::AddressBook(google::protobuf::Arena*)

It is also important that I have windows (alas) and the main goal is to get a wasm file.
I will be very grateful for an answer

You need to compile and link the generated addressbook.pb.cc too...

Hooray, I figured it out, maybe my answer will be useful. Compile with this command:
emcc -L ./lib -lprotobuf idw.cpp ./proto/addressbook.pb.cc -Oz -s WASM=1 -s --no-entry -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -o idw.wasm

The files of the .lib folder were taken from here: https://github.com/dsyer/protobuf-wasm
